# Will my ceiling mount projector screen be OK like this?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, projector

My projector screen is 27lb and I hung it on the ceiling. One side does have a joist but the other side doesn't line up to a joist so I had to hang the left over side on drywall with a bolt which claims to hold 30lb.

Do you think it will be OK?

I don't want my ceiling to collapse and I'm having anxiety over this. My bf say it's fine because one side already has a joist which means there isn't much left of the weight for the other side to hold.

Comment: Ceiling won't collapse, but possible that bolt might pull out of the hole.  Blame bf if it does and it is all his fault.

Comment: Why I almost always hang projector screens on chains. A hook for the chain can always go into a joist or stud, and the chains will hold the screen even if it does not line up with stud/joist spacing.

Comment: Remember, it's not the weight of the screen that you have to be concerned about, but the weight of you (or your boyfriend, or possibly one of his drunken buddies) _pulling_ the screen down. There will be much more than 30 lbs of force applied while it's being pulled down (or while giving that tug that causes it to roll back up). Drop the anxiety, but do be concerned about your mounting method.

Answer (score 3):

Those drywall hangers ratings are based on installation in a wall, where the forces are very different than a ceiling. Wall installation results in shear forces on the drywall, while ceiling installation results in pull out forces.

What you should do is get a piece of 1/2 or 3/4 inch plywood (or even a 2x4 if you don't need the slimness) and screw that in to two joists, then attach your screen to that plywood.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the anchor type.

Some are made specifically for the ceiling mount.

They are exposed to different forces than the wall anchors.

If you used wrong anchor, they might give up in time.

Here are some examples all suited for drywall, but there is a significant difference.

[image: drywall]

From the left: good one but not good for the ceiling.

Second from the left is best for the ceiling since it spreads the forces.

Third is also good for drywall but not so for the ceiling.

Last is good, but just cheaper version of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a spot near the loose (drywall attached) end where you can the screw the bracket into a joist.

It doesn't have to be right at the end, so long as it's closer to the loose end than to the other end it's good.

you might have to dill a hole in the bracket. if you do make sure that the hole and the screw won't interfere with the operation of the screen.

Comment: A picture, drawing, sketch, _something_ would help clarify your suggestion. I'm lost...

Comment: a picture would help. yes.  having not seen the screen (a projection screen not a flat panel display) i'm offering generic advice. I'm imagining some sort of ceiling mounted spool in a box that supports a pendant projection surface.

Comment: And, of all the roll-down projector screens that I've seen (similar, I'm sure to the one you're envisioning), I have no idea how one might use the factory brackets anywhere _except_ the factory bracket mount positions. Hence my suggestion that you give some sort of additional detail about how one might mount/modify the bracket to a joist yet where, "It doesn't have to be right at the end", as I've personally never seen one like that. Maybe my experience is more limited than I thought?